# preg_replace regex for getting weight and search term for recipe string

Tags: php, regex, search, replace, preg-replace

I have a set of data for items in recipes, they all follow a similar format.

```
2 ripe avocados, halved, stoned, peeled, coarsely chopped
125g tin chickpeas, rinsed, drained  
250g cherry tomatoes, chopped  
2 fresh red birdseye chillies, seeded, finely chopped  
1/2 cup coriander leaves
1 tablespoon lime juice  
2 tablespoons plain flour  
2 teaspoons sumac  
8 (about 800g) white fish fillets (such as bream or whiting)
1 tablespoon vegetable oil
```

What I am looking to do it ignore everything after the first comma (,) as its irrelevant for that I am looking for. So then the dataset would look like the following:

```
2 ripe avocados
125g tin chickpeas  
250g cherry tomatoes
2 fresh red birdseye chillies
1/2 cup coriander leaves
1 tablespoon lime juice  
2 tablespoons plain flour  
2 teaspoons sumac  
8 (about 800g) white fish fillets (such as bream or whiting)
1 tablespoon vegetable oil
```

Now remove anything within brackets, resulting in the following dataset:

```
2 ripe avocados
125g tin chickpeas  
250g cherry tomatoes
2 fresh red birdseye chillies
1/2 cup coriander leaves
1 tablespoon lime juice  
2 tablespoons plain flour  
2 teaspoons sumac  
8 white fish fillets
1 tablespoon vegetable oil
```

Finally, I would like to remove some set words, there isn't a large set of them, I have a list, but in this example, it would be the words 'tin','fresh' and 'ripe'. Resulting in the two things I am looking for, which is the search term, and the volume. As below:

```
2 avocados
125g chickpeas  
250g cherry tomatoes
2 red birdseye chillies
1/2 cup coriander leaves
1 tablespoon lime juice  
2 tablespoons plain flour  
2 teaspoons sumac  
8 white fish fillets
1 tablespoon vegetable oil
```

Surly this is possible with regex, at the moment I am using explode and other iterations etc to try to achieve this as regex isn't my strongest point, but its not the correct way to go about it.

Any assistance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Ultimately, the reason for this is because I have a database of food products and volumes that I am trying to compare against.

[example here](http://regexr.com/3bkds)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
,.*$|\([^)]+\)|\b(tin|fresh|ripe)\b
```

with '' (then you might need to replace ' {2,}' with ' ' to deal with e.g. `125g tin chickpeas` going to `125g  chickpeas` (double space).

The `,.*$` matches everything from a comma to end of line, the `\([^)]+\)` replaces matches in brackets (no nested brackets) and the `tin|fresh|ripe` match the words 'tin', 'fresh' and 'ripe'. The `\b` matches a 'word boundary', so that e.g. the 'ripe' in 'stripe' wouldn't be removed.

In PHP you could use something like [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) e.g.

```
$recipe = preg_replace('/,.*$|\([^)]+\)|\b(tin|fresh|ripe)\b/', '', $recipe)
// fix multiple-spaces
$recipe = preg_replace('/ {2,}/', ' ', $recipe)
```

Comment: Thank you @mathmatical.coffee, that solution worked for me. If I wanted to take it a step further to get the amount at the start, i.e. "1 1/2 cups" or "100g" what's the best regex method. Have [example here](http://regexr.com/3bkdj): `^(\d+)( |\/|.)?(\d+)?( |\/)?(\d{1})?
(Tablespoon(s)?|teaspoon(s)?|tsp|tbsp|tbs|tbl|tb|t|fluid|fl|ounce(s)|oz|package(s)|pkg|pint|pt|quart(s)?|qt(s)?|gallon(s)?|gal(s)?|lb(s)?|pound(s)?|cup(s)?|C|c|gram(s)?|kilogram(s)?|kg|liter|L|l|milliliter|mL|ml|)`

Comment: What you've got looks OK (though just as a note, `\d{1}` can just be `\d`, and `(s)?` may as well be `s?`, and `C|c|t|L|l` could be `[CctLl]` and so on). You just put some capturing brackets (i.e., brackets) around the thing you want to extract and then get that captured group afterwards.